# How to merge a array as a column in a eloquent\query object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

1) There is a web service delivering a array with employer data as :

```
RH = [ employee_id: 132 
      workplace: {
                  workplace_id: 433
                  workplace_name: 'Rio Grande do Norte'
 ....and so on.... }
]
```

2) And there is a datatable that delivery other dates and employee_id data too.

TABLE_COLUMNS: "id", "employee_id", "status",  "weight", "... and so on..."

QUESTION: There is a way to merge the array as a column in a query object like this?

```
return $query :
```

RESULTS:

```
"id", "employee_id", "status",  "weight",..."**workplace_name**"
```

ps.: Excuse-me if a newbie or a non-sense question, I'm new in Laravel,php, developer and so on.

Comment: May be constructing a model, using model->fill(() or model->fill_raw()
 with that array and create a relationship between models, is it will work?? Anyone has a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two arrays you can use plain PHP

```
$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2)
```